# Null transaction in In-App purchase for ios Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am developing in-app purchase modal for my ios application but I had a problem with transaction which returns NULL value.
Here is the code of the method which make the update of transactions:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

    switch (transaction.transactionState) {

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:[self UnlockPurchase];

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;

        default:
              NSLog(@"Value of the transaction :  %@", transaction.transactionState);
            break;
    }

}

}
```

The result which was shown in the output window (in Xcode) was:

```
Transaction Failed 
Value of the transaction :  (null)
```

Comment: You have minor code issues which may or may not be causing your problem. First, `transactionState` property is not an object, it's NSInteger, and `%@` placeholder which you use in NSLog is for NSObjects. Second, you are missing `break` keyword in SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed case. `default` case is for when none of the other specified cases are true - it's not an equivalent of "finally" block of try-catch-finally.

Comment: thanks for your response but I made your suggestions and the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

You can't print it with "%@", try "%d". If the state had happened to have a value other than zero, then you would have had a crash instead of it just printing "(null)".

Comment: thanks, but I print it with %d and the result was 0.